# ¿Cómo utilizar exit() para finalizar un script en linux?

Tags: linux, bash, script

Comunidad, les comento mi problema:
Estoy en medio de la creación de un script para para gestionar grupos, y en el case quiero poner un `exit`para finalizar el script cuando el usuario ingresa 0 (que es la salida). El problema surge que probé varias opciones que encontré en la web y ninguna me funciona, todas me dan error.
Mi SO es CentOS 7 3.10.0-862.e17. 
Agradezco cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar.-

aquí el código hasta el momento (alguna sugerencia de algo que vean mal o no de uso será bienvenida)

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 opc=9
  3 group=""
  4
  5 echo "Registro de un nuevo grupo de usuarios"
  6 echo "para ingresar un nuevo grupo presione 1."
  7 echo "para modificar un grupo presione 2."
  8 echo "para salir presione 0 "
  9 read opc
 10
 11 case $opc in
 12 1) if [ $opc -eq 1 ]
 13 then
 14         read -p "Ingrese el nombre del grupo: " group
 15         read -p "El nombre del grupo es correcto? '$group' (s/n): " opc
 16         while [[ $opc != "s" ]] || [[ $opc != "S" ]] || [[ $opc != "n" ]] || [[ $opc != "N" ]]
 17         do
 18                 echo "Respuesta inválida. Intente de Nuevo."
 19                 read -p "El Nombre del grupo es correcto? 'group' (s/n): " opc
 20                 while [[ $opc == "N" ]] || [[ $opc == "n" ]]
 21                 do
 22                         read -p "Ingrese el nombre del grupo: " group
 23                         read -p "El nombre del grupo es correcto? '$group' (s/n): " opc
 24                 done
 25         done
 26 fi
 27 groupadd $group
 28 grep $group /etc/group | cut -d : -f 3;;
 29
 30 0) exit();
 31
 32 esac
```

Comment: Ahí está el humilde código, y aclaro (aunque en los `echo`al inicio se aprecia) la opción `0` hace que se cierre el script, y falta terminar, además de probarlo completamente hasta lo escrito. Gracias! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Las funciones en `shell` se llaman sólo por su nombre. `exit`, al ser una función, sólo se llama como tal `exit` y no `exit()`.

Al decir `exit()` estás definiendo una función que esperaría que fuera de las formas.

```
f() {
    :
}

# O

f() { :; }
```

Otra cosa, que no viene al caso de tu pregunta, pero si de la funcionalidad de tu programa, es que tu script puede no funcionar como quisieras por el uso del operador `||`.

Algo que te serviría sería algo, por ejemplo, así.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Registro de un nuevo grupo de usuarios"
echo "para ingresar un nuevo grupo presione 1."
echo "para modificar un grupo presione 2."
echo "para salir presione 0 "

declare -l opc  #  Al hacer uso del parametro "-l", cualquier valor que
                #+ se le asigne a la variable "opc", sera convertido 
                #+ a minusculas, por lo que reducira las opciones "S" y "N"
                #+ a considerar mas adelante.
read opc

case "$opc" in
    1 ) 

        read -p "Ingrese el nombre del grupo: " group
        read -p "El nombre del grupo es correcto? '$group' (s/n): " opc

        #                  _____ Uso el operador de pareo de expresiones regulares.
        #                 |
        while [[ ! "$opc" =~ ^(s|n)$ ]]  
        #                        |_____  #  Hago uso de una expresion regular que busca
                                         #+ el patron de buscar o una sola "s" o una sola "n"
                                         #+ minusculas, es decir, busca un "s" o "n" para 
                                         #+ poder negarlo (con !). Es decir, continua el ciclo
                                         #+ mientras no encuentre ni "s" ni "n" solos.
        do
            echo "Respuesta inválida. Intente de Nuevo."
            read -p "El Nombre del grupo es correcto? 'group' (s/n): " opc

            while [[ "$opc" = "n"  ]]
            do
                read -p "Ingrese el nombre del grupo: " group
                read -p "El nombre del grupo es correcto? '$group' (s/n): " opc
            done
        done
        groupadd "$group"
        grep "$group" /etc/group | cut -d : -f 3

    ;;

    0 ) 
        exit
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Marco por la explicación y el ejemplo, el tema de la condición el año pasado para uno con la finalidad de modificar permisos de arhivos, probé hacer la condición como la pusiste en la respuesta `[[ "$opc" =~ ^(s/n)$ ]]`, pero no encontré la manera exacta, pese a consultas y lecturas web, por que lo hice si no igual que lo tengo ahora muy parecido, fue la salida que le encontré y funcionaba (aunque no lo creas :D). En fin, agradezco tu tiempo y tu lección!

Comment: Ahora una consulta de la condición,  acepta mayúsculas también??? o debe agregarse (digo para evitar problemas en caso que el usuario tenga mayúsculas activado), no se si esto será correcto `^(s|nS|N)$` o `^(s|n|S|N)$`??

Comment: No voy a contestar a tus preguntas directamente porque creo que evidencian una falla de mi respuesta: no documenté mi código. Así que lo documentaré para que quede claro.

Comment: Por cierto, no sé si copiaste y pegaste mal tu fragmento de código, pero yo no escribí un `[[ "$opc" =~ ^(s/n)$ ]]` sino un `[[ ! "$opc" =~ ^(s|n)$ ]]`

Comment: me di cuenta luego del comentario, es un pipe y no un slash.

Comment: Bien, así simplemente toma minúsculas, para que acepte también mayúsculas, aplica alguna de las ideas?

Comment: No, acepta lo que sea, pero lo fuerza a ser minúsculas para reducir el espacio de opciones. ¿Ya te funcionó el programa?

Comment: si funcionó, muchas gracias! ahora estoy con las otras opciones, baja y modificación de los grupos, pero ya me sirve para el de administración de usuarios. de nuevo gracias por tu tiempo!!! Atentamente un novato de linux.

Comment: Si te fue de utilidad mi respuesta, márcala como la adecuada y/o dale una puntuación positiva para que otras personas que tengan una pregunta similar, la encuentren fácilmente